# how to delete columns by column name from an excel using python openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have an Excel worksheet from which I want to delete certain columns based on their column names using python openpyxl as the column positions aren't fixed.

Their indices can change every time i get a new report, but the column name to be deleted remains the same each time.
In the below example i want to delete columns if their names are equal to = ["To be determined","No Value","Total"]
[image]

I have tried fetching the column index number so i can delete those using index value, but it isn't working as expected.
[image]
where max_file is the excel file path and sh2 is sheet2 containing the data

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using

```
sh2.delete_cols(2,4)
```

2 is the starting column and 4 is the number of columns.

Comment: Have edited my query. The problem is i cant give a fixed index number to be deleted. The column positions change in every report, but their names remain constant. 
So either i can delete by their column names or fetch their index each time and then delete

Comment: According to the openpyxl you cant delete column by column name you should go with second option you can delete single column by using sh2.delete_cols(column_number)

Comment: Yes, so the code I have tried is not fetching me the column number when looped through the data where column names="To be determined","No Value", and "Total".

Comment: Because you gave 1, 1 in range() as range takes first parameter as the starting index and second parameter as the ending index (not included). So apparently your outer loop is not working because you gave same starting and ending index. I guess you were suppose to pass 0, 1

Answer (score 0):

## Function to delete multiple columns by column name

```
# Even if your cell names are not like 'B12' instead only 'B'. That also can be done just let me know in the comment
list_of_cell_names_need_to_be_deleted = ['B1', 'C2', 'E7', 'A5']

def delete_columns_by_name(list_of_cell_names_need_to_be_deleted):

    for i in list_of_cell_names_need_to_be_deleted:

        # For the first iteration first it splits 'B1' to ('B',1) and stores 'B' to the assigned variable below
        cell_name_only_alpha = openpyxl.utils.cell.coordinate_from_string(i)[0]

        # After splitting it, we will store the index of the letter exctrated ( here for first iteration it will be 'B' and hence index will be 2 )
        index_value = openpyxl.utils.cell.column_index_from_string(cell_name_only_alpha)
        
        # Now let's delete the colu
        # If you don't know what is ws, here is a brief information
        # wb - Used to mention the name of the file.
        # ws - Used to mention the sheet name of the file. (There may be more than one sheet within an excel file)
        # For more info : https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html
        ws.delete_cols(index_value,1)



delete_columns_by_name(list_of_cell_names_need_to_be_deleted)

# NOTE : At the end don't forget to save the file
# Code to save the file : wb.save(name_of_file_here)

wb.save(name_of_file_here)
```